# How to send Ajax request in pug template?

Tags: javascript, ajax, pug

I would like to send Ajax request in pug template file.

```
form#payment-form()
  section
    label(for="amount")
      input#amount(name="amount" type="tel" min="1" placeholder="Amount"                         value="10")
script(src="scripts/jquery.js")
script.
  (function () {
    var amount = $('#amount').val();
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/posturl",
      data: {'amount':amount},
      success: function(){},
      dataType: 'json'
    });
  })()
```

But it doesn't work, how to do it?
I want to know how to send ajax request in embeded javascript of pug file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To me there seems to be two issues

1. You have put unnecessary tabs in your function under `(function (){`
2. You need to use `document.ready` to ensure that HTML content is
   ready. You can avoid this if you don't really care for DOM once you have the response

check a working example below

```
doctype html
html
  head
    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js')
    script.
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);
      }});
      });
  body
    #div1
      h2 Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Here there is no problem with your pug template (maybe just you can remove `()`after `#payment-form()` because it is empty and it's not a mixin). But with your JS, you send the AJAX request immediatly, you should bind it to an event (click on a button, keypress on an input, etc.). Then you have to be sure you put your lib `jquery.js` in a directory you can access from your browser with `scripts/jquery.js`. If it's still not work after this change please report more precisely your error (open the console to get the messages, get us the behavior you expect and the behavior you get).